# how to efficiently detect out of disk errors in rust (sync_all very slow)

Tags: rust, cloud, nfs, disk

I have a cloud service written in Rust that does a ton of writing to NFS. We noticed in the [terrible] case where the NFS staging disk gets full, the server does not get notified of this error.

Reading the Rust documentation, this seems to be expected and the answer is to call `sync_all` which will return disk errors: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html

They say "Files are automatically closed when they go out of scope. Errors detected on closing are ignored by the implementation of Drop. Use the method sync_all if these errors must be manually handled."

So this works, however, the performance degradation caused by adding `sync_all` is not acceptable to the business. Given the usage profile, the change is enormous. Things that took 5 seconds now take 25 seconds, for example. I've estimated that on a local SSD a call to `sync_all` adds anything between 5 ms to 10 ms.

So I am looking for an alternative solution rather than just calling `sync_all`. Is there another way to check for out-of-disk space errors that is quick?

The documentation mentions that the implementation of Drop ignores errors on close. Could I provide a custom implementation that does not? How would I even do that?

Comment: *"Things that took 5 seconds now take 25 seconds"* - are you saying a single `sync_all` call took 25 seconds? or is this multiple file operations together that add up?

Comment: No, in the order of 5,000+ calls does. As I said, this is a write-intensive application.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on your actual requirements but one possible solution could be doing the `sync_all` out of band, that way your immediate work isn't hindered but you'll still receive the errors at some point:

```rust
pub fn out_of_SeqCstband_cleanup(writes: usize) {
    let keep_on = std::sync::Arc::new(std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool::new(true));
    let (input, out) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<std::fs::File>();
    let cleanup = std::thread::spawn({
        let keep_on = std::sync::Arc::clone(&keep_on);
        move || {
            while let Ok(f) = out.recv() {
                if dbg!(f.sync_all()).is_err() {
                    // signal that an error occured, the main thread should now stop trying to write
                    keep_on.store(false, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::SeqCst);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    for i in 0..writes {
        if !keep_on.load(std::sync::atomic::Ordering::SeqCst) {
            break;
        }
        let mut f = std::fs::File::create(format!("{i}.txt")).unwrap();
        // fake some work that is being done
        #[allow(deprecated)] std::thread::sleep_ms(5);
        write!(f, "hello").unwrap();
        input.send(f).unwrap();
    }
    drop(input);
    cleanup.join().unwrap();
}
```

The drawback being that you don't immediately know the disc is full but may learn about it only later, after you've tried writing further files.
Another thing to note is that if the writes are the bottleneck this might grow the channel indefinitely (or with a bound channel at some point end up wating inline again).

[Crude mini benchmark on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=48bcece8d765b529ec23e6573e48073e)